# how do i troubleshoot Error response from daemon?

Tags: docker, error-handling, dockerfile, virtual-machine, daemon

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: server misbehaving

Comment: Is your registry using https or just http? I've gotten errors like that on an insecure registry

Comment: How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

**sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf**

*and then*

**change nameserver to 8.8.8.8**

Comment: How to fix this in windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

change for your ip server
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver **ip-server**
options edns0 trust-ad
search .